# Blazor server side Azure AD MFA issue

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, blazor-server-side, azureportal

I'm facing an issue that users get (randomly) a loop of redirect **or **an MFA error: "invalid_grant aadsts65001 the user or administrator has not consented to use the application".

Only after visiting **https://aka.ms/mfasetup** site, all works again.

Blazor server code snip:

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                       .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(o => {
                           o.UsePkce = true;
                           o.ClientId = "clientId";
                           o.TenantId = "tenantId";
                           o.Domain = "domain.onmicrosoft.com";
                           o.Instance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com";
                           o.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
                           o.Scope.Add("scopeApi1");
                           o.Scope.Add("offline_access");
                           o.ResponseType = "code";
                           var defaultBackChannel = new HttpClient();                               defaultBackChannel.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Origin", "appx");
                           o.Backchannel = defaultBackChannel;
                       });


services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.SaveTokens = true;            
                options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
                    {
                        // Here you will be able to see the accesstoken.
                        var accessToken = context.TokenEndpointResponse.AccessToken;
                        var refreshToken = context.TokenEndpointResponse.RefreshToken;
                    };
                });


_Host.cshtml

var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
var refreshToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("refresh_token");

<component type="typeof(App)" param-AccessToken="@accessToken" param-RefreshToken="@refreshToken" render-mode="Server" />


App.razor:

[Parameter]
public string AccessToken { get; set; }
[Parameter]
public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
```

Any idea what could be the cause for such issue?

Giving an "Grant admin consent" for the application in azure portal. **DIDN'T HELP**.

Adding prompt=consent to the Azure url.. **DIDN'T HELP**.

**DIDN'T HELP**.

```
o.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async context =>
        {
            // Ensure that prompt is not set to "none" here
            context.ProtocolMessage.Prompt = "select_account";
        },
        // ...
    };
```

Comment: I found that using the popup login mode instead of redirect made this experience more consistent in Blazor. The other observation was that this is generally a client-side issue outside of our configuration. Only some users would experience this issue but they would also have trouble accessing other MSAL sites like [portal.office.com](https://portal.office.com).